# To remove lonely closing anchor tag in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a huge data (html code) stored in my SQL Server where as after recent update in code, there are some lonely closing anchor tags ('') left over, which I want to remove from my data (/ code) using a SQL query.

The following is an example:

```
some random data<id><a></a><class></a></id></class>
```

I'm trying to achieve this conversion:

Input:

```
Some Random Data<id>data<id><a></a><class>  </a> </id></class><class>  </a>  </id></class> Some Random data
```

Output:

```
Some Random Data<id>data<id><a></a><class></id></class><class>    </id></class> Some Random data
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a task for SQL Server; SQL Server doesn't functionality to parse HTML; especially when it's malformed HTML. Seems like you need to use, and fix, whatever process you used before to update the values (again). As we have no context of that that application is, we can do very little to help you here.

Comment: You can, of course, just do a `REPLACE(..., '</a>', '')` to remove all of these tags, but that can end up destroying valid code. SQL Server can't process HTML semantically unless it also happens to be valid XML (which this explicitly is not). Combine that with a lack of regex support and you end up with something you really don't want to do in T-SQL if at all possible. Fixing invalid HTML without destroying the markup entirely is not an easy problem in general, which is why separate software like HTML Tidy/libtidy exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a replace command for this.

```
REPLACE(columnname, '</a>', '')
```

Comment: What about all the valid anchor tags in the OP's data?